# How to calculate percent deviation from long-term monthly median using PeriodIndex data in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some `PeriodIndex` data in `Pandas` that looks roughly as follows:

```
Period    Spam    Ham
2019-11   30      40
2019-12   49      57
2020-01   4       40
...       ...     ...
```

It's several years' worth of data, and I want to be able to find the month-by-month change for 2020 on the median and average of all the same months in preceding years. So, for example, I would like to be able to say that `Spam` in March 2020 was X% above or below the median of `Spam` in all the March periods in the dataset.

The data is on a `Pandas` `PeriodIndex`. I can get close to what I want with the following:

```
def get_monthly_median(data, categories, start, end):
  df = data[target_categories].loc[start:end]
  return df.groupby(df.index.month).median()

ef get_baseline_normalised(data, categories, start, end, bline_start, bline_end):
  baseline = get_monthly_median(data, categories, bline_start, bline_end)
  df = data[categories].loc[start:end]
  df = df.groupby(df.index.month).median()
  return ((df/baseline) - 1) * 100
```

But then the months end up as numbers, and I have to start stuffing about with custom sorting to make a plot in the right order of, say, an annual window starting in October (month 10). Also, I would prefer to use `month_name()` rather than month number as it's more explicit, but `PeriodIndex` does not appear to have that implemented.

I think there must be a smart solution using `rollforward()` and `rollbackward()` or something like those, but I can't seem to work it out. Can you help?

UPDATE:

With `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).median()` I get:

```
Period  Spam    Ham
2014-12 726.0   1948.0
2015-01 665.0   2111.0
2015-02 621.0   1478.0
2015-03 723.0   1741.0
```

which is what I started with. What I want is more:

```
Month   Spam_median   Ham_median
March   Number        Number
```

Comment: does `df.groupby(df.index).median()` fix the problem?

Comment: Sadly not. That just leaves me with what I have — monthly period data.

Comment: can you show us your expected output?

Comment: I've added those now, @PabloC I Appreciate your help.